# Websocket communication works with localtunnel but not ngrok

Tags: websocket, python-asyncio, ngrok, localtunnel

I created a little multiplayer game to learn how Python's `asyncio` worked. I tested everything on `localhost` first -- everything worked. I then used `ngrok` to expose my `localhost` so I could play with some friends. However, every time they connected through `ngrok`, their client never updated. The client would send messages through the web socket, but it wouldn't receive anything. For a long time, I thought it was a bug in my code. Then, I tried using `localtunnel` instead of `ngrok`, and to my surprise, it worked as if it were just `localhost` again.

So my question is: what differences are there between `localtunnel` and `ngrok` that allowed the web socket communication to work properly in `localtunnel`?

Comment: Let me know if posting any code would help!